# cakephp nest array from sub into sub relation

Tags: cakephp, find, multidimensional-array

I need result from 4 tables in the following format

```
array(
       (int)0=>array(
              'Fee'=>array(
                     'id'=>'1',
                     'student_id'=>array(
                                   'id'=>'22',
                                    'name'=>'Jhon',
                                    'age'=>'15',
                                    'class_id'=>array(
                                               'id'=>'6',
                                               'class'=>'4th',
                                                ....
                                                ),
                                     ......
                                     ),
                       'paid'=>'2000',
                       'date'=>'2014-11-11 11:11:11',
                       'user_id'=>array(
                                  'id'=>'3',
                                  'name'=>'Smith',
                                   ....
                                   )
                      )
       )
 )
```

table wise

```
fee.id, fee.paid, 
student.id,student.name,
class.name,
user.name
```

tables structure and associations

```
fees(id,student_id,paid,date,...,user_id)
```

linked to students and users tables

```
students(id,user_id,class_id,....)
```

linked to users table

```
classes(id,name,....)
```

belongs to student

```
users(id,name,email,password,age,role....)
```

partially belongs to students
  some records are for admins login
  while some belongs to student bcz they also needs to login

I got tired trying joins, contain, thread
how can i get required result

Comment: That would be totally incompatible with all the CakePHP magic, so the first question is, why? What do you need this for? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your tables and models have followed the normal naming conventions and you have the relationships set up between them correctly then the following:

```
$fees = $this->Fee->find('all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Fee.id',
            'Fee.paid',
            'Fee.date'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Student' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Student.id',
                    'Student.name',
                    'Student.age',
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Class' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'id',
                            'class'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'User' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'id',
                    'name'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Would produce:

```
$fees = array(
    (int)0 => array(
        'Fee' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'paid' => '2000',
            'date' => '2014-11-11 11:11:11',
            'Student' => array(
                'id' => 22,
                'name' => 'John',
                'age' => '15',
                'Class' => array(
                    'id' => 6,
                    'class' => '4th'
                )
            ),
            'User' => array(
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Smith'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int)1 => //next Fee
);
```

If you still need the array exactly as you put originally then it's not too complicated to do some rearrangement of the array using php.

P.S You will need to make that on your Student, Class and User models you set:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

in order for the 'contain' part of the query to work :)